# Twitter URL encoding

Tags: php, url, twitter

We're about to launch a little twitter Christmas competition, and I've run into a little snag.

To enter, people will need to post a tweet in the following format:

```
@user blah, blah, blah #hashtag
```

Currently, I have a form where they enter their answer (the blah, blah, blah) and a PHP script which encodes the entire statement and adds on the twitter url:

```
http://www.twitter.com/home?status=%40user%20blah%2Cblah%2Cblah%20%23hashtag
```

Then takes the user to twitter and puts the status in the update field.

However, whilst the spaces (%20) are decoded fine the @ and # characters remain as %40 & %23 respectively, even when the tweet is posted. I cannot put the actual characters in the url as twitter mistakes this for a search.

Is there any way to solve this? I'd like to do it without requiring username & password etc if possible.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rich, can you elaborate on the "Then takes the user to twitter" part? Are you just doing a redirect from PHP after processing their text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encode the spaces as + and it works:
http://twitter.com/home?status=%40user+blah%2Cblah%2Cblah+%23hashtag

Comment: I also needed to take out the www then it worked a treat! Thanks!

Comment: Taking out the www didn't work for me, but replacing the spaces with + worked like a charm

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Twitter fails to decode the + signs to spaces. Or actually it only decodes the first +, and then leaves the rest. Whoever wrote Twitter's custom URL decoding needs to be shot in very painful ways.

Comment: Actually, twitter.com does not work for me, but twitter.com/home does. Apparently twitter decodes the query string differently for each possible URL you can call.

Comment: Like @mcv said, Twitter is not decoding '+' signs properly. Of course, you can add spaces to your status url by - well - not encoding, which could be a bad idea.

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same problem, and the solution was very simple.

Just use
`http://twitter.com/home?status=`
 instead of
`http://www.twitter.com/home?status=`
 and it'll work as expected, even if the text isn't in ASCII.

If you want to know more details about this strange behavior see this blog post:
http://www.kilometer0.com/blog/2010/01/21/twitter-status-urls-and-ampersands/

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Cheers for that :)
I mentioned this in my chosen answer above too!

Answer (score 2):

You could try just posting right to Twitter:

```
<form action="http://www.twitter.com/home" method="GET">
    <textarea name="status">
```

...

Comment: Keep it simple, eh? Didn't think of that!

However, I'd like to have more control over the structure of the tweet, without relying on JS too much.

Thanks though, this may be the way!

Comment: I know what you mean... I personally wouldn't mind relying on JS (as long as it only works when JS is enabled, obviously), as http://twitter.com wants JS as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. At least when using the new Twitter layout ... this:

http://twitter.com/home?status=This+is+a+test+%26+So+is+this

... redirects to this (when logged in):

http://twitter.com/?status=This%20is%20a%20test%20&%20So%20is%20this

(notice the unencoded &) ... and the tweet-in-waiting becomes:

This is a test

:(

Myriad adjustments and variations didn't help. (Sigh.)

Admittedly sketchy workaround: Change & (%26) to + (%2B). It may be advisable do this with plain text, before (re-)introducing entities into the equation (e.g., don't change %26 to %2B). Measure twice, cut once, as they say.

Answer (score 1):

After a wile i got this... You have to send as UTF8 encoded, you can use javascript to do that but I prefere PHP because my text also came from the tatabase....

`<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=<?= urlencode(utf8_encode( 'HERE I USE THE TITLE OF MY ARTICLE FROM DATABASE' )) ?>&lang=pt&url=<?= urlencode('http://jadielalves.com?s=stackoverflow') ;?>" target="_blank">SHARE ON TWITTER you can also put a twitter icon here... </a>`

Answer (score 0):

I've done it using this function from MDN

> To be more stringent in adhering to RFC 3986 (which reserves !, ', (, ), and *), even though these characters have no formalized URI delimiting uses, the following can be safely used:

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
            return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function (c) {
                return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
            });
        }
```

> [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)