# Twitter message syntax

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am trying to post a message via Twitter API and it works as long as I have a simple text string, however, as soon as I add a URL into my message it is not posted. Do I need to escape some characters?

WORKS:

```
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Trying out a new online tool with a monthly complimentary subscription. via @mySite'));
```

DOESN'T WORK:

```
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Trying out a new online tool with a monthly complimentary subscription at: http://mysite.org via @mySite'));
```

Comment: Can you post the actual URL you are using instead of 'http://mysite.org'? Also, see [Twitter URL encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903244/twitter-url-encoding) for helpful tips.

Comment: What does `post()` return. Do you have an error message?

Comment: Nevermind. I rewrote URL to be shorter and it posted OK. Go figure...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do URL Encoding in the message.

Try:

`$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => urlencode('Trying out a new online tool with a monthly complimentary subscription at: http://mysite.org via @mySite')));`